# Should I optimise images and videos from react before uploading to S3 or I optimise it in S3, which is better?

Tags: react-native, image, amazon-s3, video

Building a react-native app where images and videos are uploaded to S3 bucket, but the images are sometimes very large, and after uploading, when I get the image back, it returns a large image that takes a long time to display on the app. I've tried to optimize it from the app, but it seems not to reduce really well.

And for videos, uploading videos takes a long time to upload.

How do you upload videos and images fast and optimized from react-native? Do you optimize from the app or on S3?

Comment: It's always better to do the optimising operations in the backend. You can also check https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image , this helps in caching images.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on a team where we build a social media like web application where users can upload images and videos. The approach we took is:

Images and Videos are uploaded to S3 as is and we made use of S3 Events (S3:ObjectCreated:* to be specific) to trigger a lambda that would optimise it and store it in the same S3 bucket (could be different as well) under a different common prefix which is referenced while serving Media.